# How to pass empty bytes to a solidity function in Remix?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I couldnt figure out a way to pass empty bytes to a solidity function on remix.
Here is my function

```
    function checkEmptyBytes(bytes calldata _data) external pure returns (string memory){
        if (_data.length > 0){
            return "NOT_ZERO";
        }
        return "ZER0";
        
    }
```

On remix, I have to pass _data such that it should return "ZERO"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can input the `[]` expression representing an empty array.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If I use `[]` as a function parameter, when calling one function from another in Solidity, I get `TypeError: Unable to deduce common type for array elements.`

Comment: @LukeHutchison Depending on the called function param type, you need to actually declare the empty array - not just use the `[]` expression. Example: `string[] memory arr; innerFunction(arr);` for the `innerFunction` accepting `string[] memory`.

Comment: I'm trying to call a superconstructor from a constructor, and there's no chance to declare a local in that way before calling the superconstructor. I can't declare an empty array field that way either. It only works for locals. See: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/12401

Comment: @LukeHutchison It's currently (v0.8) not possible to both declare and pass a dynamic-length array in a one-line statement. Having said that, I responded with a workaround in the Github issue.

Comment: @PetrHejda You can also pass empty arrays like so `new address[](0)` (I chose address type here, but it works for any type)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use 0x (normally a bytes value is in the form of 0x123456, while 0x is basically an empty bytes).